# Reflection API in Factory pattern

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, reflection, factory

Usually we use Factory method to deal with the problem of creating objects without having to specify the exact class of the object that will be created.

Lets say we have 5 different implementations of some logger. Here is pseudo code how that would be implemented with traditional Factory method:

```
class LoggerFactoryMethod extends AbstractFactoryMethod {
function makeLogger($param) {
    $logger = NULL;
    switch ($param) {
        case "mysql":
            $logger = new MysqlLogger;
        break;      
        case "mongo":
            $logger = new MongoLogger;
        break;      
        case "txt":
            $logger = new TxtLogger;
        break;
        case "redis":
            $logger = new RedisLogger;
        break;
        case "memcached":
            $logger = new MemcachedLogger;
        break;
        default:
            $logger = new TxtLogger;
        break;    
    }     
    return $logger;
}
```

This works fine, but having many if/else (or switch/code) conditions is not so cool. Let say tomorrow we want to add one more implementation. We will need to modify this code and to add new case condition. With this we might break the Open/Closed principle from the SOLID principles.

Instead, using Reflection API is more elegant and doesn't need significant change for new implementation. The same example using Reflection API would be :

```
class LoggerFactoryMethod extends AbstractFactoryMethod {
function makeLogger($param) {
    $allowed_implementations = array('mysql','mongo', 'txt', 'redis' , 'memcached');
    $class = new ReflectionClass($param);

    if (!in_array($param, $allowed_implementations) || !($class->IsInstantiable())){
        return null;
    }

    return $class->newInstance();
}
```

Are there any disadvantages using Reflection API instead traditional Factory pattern (using if/else conditions) ? Is it good practice to use it ?

Comment: I can't speak to PHP, but 'in general' (other languages, reflection is generally more expensive than constructors, so you are inflicted with a resource overhead) Plus you are actually limiting your factory pattern, Because you are assuming that the constructors are all no-op, if you have some with operands, then you will need logic to enable that. In general factory has the long list of if/then/else or some kind of dynamic binding, but an if/then or switch stmt is often more tractable+faster and easier to debug (at the cost of more physical code) So (ignoring any PHP issues its a tradeoff '?')

Comment: I agree with @mawalker and would prefer the traditional switch implementation. There is nothing wrong with simple conditional statements when you want to solve simple condition. What you suggest as improved factory method also needs to be modified when new logger implementation is added because of $allowed_implementations.

Comment: As @iluwatar pointed out, if you want to be supper flexible and pay the **reflection cost** just extract the `$allowed_implementations` collection allowing it to be configured as a system / application property, so your factory will always find it.

Comment: 1. Not sure if the reflection is too expensive with PHP because it is interpreted language. It can do reflection much easier (cheaper) than  compiled languages.  

2. $allowed_implementations is not necessary for the reflection. It is just put as example if we maybe want to do some filter.

Answer (score 2):

I have a suggestion for your use case, although it doesn't solve your question, but it's another approach that you can take for your factory.

Let's say you have a config file to store what implementation you want to use:

```
# path/to/config.php
<?php
return [
    'mysql' => Some\Namespace\MysqlLogger::class,   
    'mongo'=> Some\Namespace\MongoLogger::class,
    'txt' => Some\Namespace\TxtLogger::class,
    'redis' => Some\Namespace\RedisLogger::class,
    'memcached' => Some\Namespace\MemcachedLogger::class,
];
```

and your factory would take those and create logger based on parameter passed and initialised based on config.

```
class LoggerFactoryMethod extends AbstractFactoryMethod {
protected $logger = [];
public function __construct()
{
    $this->logger = require('path/to/config.php');
}

function makeLogger($param = 'txt') {
    return new $this->logger[$param];
}
```

Later when yu need to add or remove any logger, you can just add or remove from the list in config.
Just try to implement LoggerInterface to each logger so whatever your implementation will not breaks your code. There is a PSR standard interface for logger here: [PSR-3 Log](https://packagist.org/packages/psr/log) following this [PSR-3 Log Description](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-3-logger-interface.md)

With this i think it gives a better implementation than switch statement and doesn't require expensive reflection.

Just My Two Cents